# Reverse vector items but not the first one? C++

Tags: c++

I have a vector

```
std::vector<std::string> letters; // {{A, B, C,}, {A}, {B, C, D, E}}
```

I want to reverse the order but NOT the first letter for each vector. How do I do this?

So it would be

```
{{A, C, B}, {A}, {B, E, D, C}}
```

I tried to do:

```
std::reverse(letters.begin(), letters.end());
for (int i=0;i<letters.size();i++)
  cout << letters[i];
```

but it crashes on me

Comment: add a test condition on the number_of_elements before entering the For-loop....

Comment: Why would it crash on a vector with on element? v.begin()+1==v.end() in this case. It should probably crash on an empty vector.

Comment: 1. your loop does not "reverse letters", it prints strings starting from the second one, 2. `cout << it` is not valid without dereferencing `it`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> letters {"ABC", "A", "BCDE", ""};
  std::for_each(letters.begin(), letters.end(), [](std::string &str) { if(!str.empty()) std::reverse(str.begin() + 1, str.end()); });
  for(auto i : letters) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbed9db63e3d62e8)

### What are you doing wrong in your code:

`std::reverse(letters.begin(), letters.end());` applies to your initial vector (i.e., it reverses the order of the strings in `letters`, it doesn't reverse the strings of the vector).

Comment: Nice solution, however I think you need to check if the string is empty before calling `std::reverse`.

Comment: @SebastianK after C++11 `std::string` is null terminated. Thus, never empty. ;)

Comment: So this is valid in C++11, but not in C++98? Interesting :)

Comment: @SebastianK Yes, but solution posted uses lambdas. So applies for C++11.

Comment: When compiling this with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, I get an error: `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:1447:error: function requires a valid iterator range [__first, __last).`. `str.end()` points at the null-terminator, not after it, so when the string is empty, `str.begin() == str.end()` and the range [`str.begin() + 1`, `str.end()`) is indeed invalid.

Comment: @40two That's wrong.  `std::string` may appear null terminated in a few specific contexts, but that trailing null is not part of the string.  An empty string is still empty, `s.begin() == s.end()` on it, and `s.begin() + 1` is still undefined behavior on it.

Comment: @JamesKanze Thnx, `@MagnusHoff` already point that out :) and corrected the code. Apparently I wasn't aware of that and stupidly I assumed that null character is part of the string ;). P.S that's the main benefit from SO actually exchange of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To reverse the vector in-place, you can use `std::reverse`:

```
std::reverse(letters.begin() + 1, letters.end());
```

To reverse them on output, leaving the vector intact, you could iterate over the vector in a reverse direction using `vector::rbegin()` and `vector::rend()`